# Need help to identify an unmarked SOT23-5 IC

Tags: circuit-analysis, digital-logic, circuit-design, integrated-circuit, identification

I have come across a PCB which is a vibration sensor (switch) based motion detection logic, where on any vibration is detected, the circuit will turn on/off a load. It works in same way as a Push button soft latch. The main component in this PCB is a SOT-23-5 package and a BJT SOT-23 for load driving. The SOT-23-5 was driving the base of BJT. On some reverse engineering below is the rough connection diagram.

[image]

[image]

I am not able to figure out what this SOT-23-5 IC corresponds to. I was thinking it could be a D-Latch or a dual complementary BJT which are used for soft latch circuit. But couldn't identify one and circuit does not match that. Can anyone help me identify this IC?

Below is the state of Pin 4 and 5

[image]

Comment: Do you happen to have oscilloscope traces of how pins 4 and 5 look when the vibration sensor is triggered?

Comment: Yes.. Pin 4 was 4.5V on OFF state. and 5V on ON State. By the way 5V is the VCC. On pin 5 it is always 5V and when vibration sensor activates, it goes to 0 then comes back to 5V in 500ms. I assume this is because of the Capacitor.

Comment: Does the "Vibration Switch" generate a voltage when it vibrates? Are you sure this isn't some kind of op-amp?

Comment: No.. The Vibration sensor is just a passive switch. I think it is SW-18020P or similar

Comment: Initially I thought it was a active sensor.. But it is not.. It looks like the pin 5 is internally pulled high.. The Vibration sensor just grounds the pin like a push button

Comment: @nanofarad Pin 4 was 0V at exact pin out on ON condition and 5V on OFF condition. Sorry for the confusion. There was a voltage divider between pin 4 and BJT so at base, it was 4.5V and 5V. It is a PNP Transistor.

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words; having an actual image of the scope trace might be helpful to readers.

Comment: Ya, I agree. Unfortunately, I don't have the PCB with me anymore. Dumb me forgot to take a picture.

Comment: @nanofarad I have added an image (drawn myself based on the observations) that gives the status of pin 4 and 5. Hope that is clear

Comment: This function looks like [SN74LVC1G80](https://www.ti.com/product/SN74LVC1G80), but it toggles on a rising edge, and has a different pinout.

Comment: Like CL said, this screams 74 series D-type flipflop, but the pinout is different.

Comment: If not a D-flipflop the some kind of on/off controller.